# Algorithm for solving `subsequence with highest win rate`

Tags: algorithm, rust

##### Problem

```
Inputs:
1. min length of subsequence
2. binary sequence

outputs:
1. starting index of sequence
2. subsequence length
```

The task is to find a subsequence from the given binary sequence with highest win rate. The subsequence should be at least of given min length.

`1 = win, 0 = loss`

`win rate = number of 1s / subsequence length`

###### Example:

```
INPUT
5
01010101111100
OUTPUT
8
5
```

```
INPUT
5
10110011100
OUTPUT
3
7
```

Given below is my attempt at solving the problem. It is a brute force technique.

```rust
fn read_line<T>() -> T
where
    T: std::str::FromStr,
    <T as std::str::FromStr>::Err: std::fmt::Debug,
{
    std::io::stdin()
        .lock()
        .lines()
        .next()
        .unwrap()
        .unwrap()
        .trim()
        .parse::<T>()
        .unwrap()
}


fn exhaustive_search(min_window_size: usize, sequence: &str) -> (usize, usize) {
    let mut max_success_rate = 0_f32;
    let mut msr_window_size = 0;
    let mut msr_starting_index = 0;
    'outer: for window_size in min_window_size..=sequence.len(){
        // println!("{}", window_size);
        for ind in 0..=(sequence.len() - window_size) {
            let substr = &sequence[ind..(window_size + ind)];
            let success_rate = substr.matches('1').count() as f32 / window_size as f32;
            if success_rate > max_success_rate {
                max_success_rate = success_rate;
                msr_window_size = window_size;
                msr_starting_index = ind;
            }
            if success_rate == 1.0 {
                break 'outer;
            }
        }
    }
    (msr_starting_index+1, msr_window_size)
}


fn main() {
    let min_window_size = read_line::<usize>();
    let sequence = read_line::<String>();
    let (index, window) = exhaustive_search(min_window_size, &sequence);
    println!("{} {}", index, window);
}
```

##### Question

How can I improve the performance of this algorithm

Comment: (First asked [on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72300776/3789665).)

Comment: ((not a *review*…) I guess I'd first run-encode the input, dropping failures head&tail: `0100101111100`->12115, with an *early out* when a *success run* reaches *min length*. Then, I'd try successively growing numbers of "gaps".)

Comment: Even changing `..=` to just `..`, I get complaints (`use of undeclared crate or module \`mod_read\``): What is `mod_read`, and how do I get an online environment to recognise it?

Comment: (..= added somewhere between Rust 1.19&1.6?)

Comment: @greybeard Extremely sorry about the `mod_read` confusion, it was a separate module from where I was reading the functions. I copied the read_line function in the question but forgot to remove reference to mod_read. Corrected the code now!